# Error 415 Unsupported media type

Tags: asp.net, angular, http-headers

All of the methods *post,put,get* works fine with the backend. but on DELETE im getting the error 415 unsupported media type. I researched a lot I believe the cause of the error is the content-type header which is not set in my code. i dont know how exactly set is to application/json. i tried different ways but none work

```
private managerStore=[];
private managerSubject = new Subject();
managers = this.managerSubject.asObservable();
    async deleteManager(manager) {
    try {
        var response = await this.http.delete(this.BASE_URL + '/manager', manager).toPromise();
        this.managerStore.push(response.json());
        this.managerSubject.next(this.managerStore);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}
```

THE ERROR : Object { _body: "", status: 415, ok: false, statusText: "Unsupported Media Type".
FRONT END: ANGULAR 5 , BACKEND: ASP.NET 2

Comment: Why did you repost exact [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143420/error-415-unsupported-media-type?noredirect=1#comment87305157_50143420) as before?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this instead

```
var response = await this.http.request('delete',this.BASE_URL + '/manager',{
                      body: manager,
                      headers: new HttpHeaders({
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                      })
                }).toPromise();
```